# Transforming/pivoting a DataFrame Instance

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transform

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = dict(store=['A', 'B', 'B'], color=['red', 'black', 'black'], size=['small', 'medium', 'small'], quantity=[2, 4, 1])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which looks like this:

```
  store  color    size  quantity
0     A    red   small         2
1     B  black  medium         4
2     B  black   small         1
```

What I want to do is the `pivot` function to create a new data frame that uses the `store` column as a header and the the `quantity` value for each of the unique row values of the `color` and `size` columns. So it should look like this:

```
       A   B
black  0   5
red    2   0 
small  2   1
medium 0   4
```

Can this be done? Something like `df.pivot(columns='store')` seems to be the way to go ...

Comment: `melt` then pivot: `df.melt(['store', 'quantity']).pivot_table(index='value', columns='store', values='quantity', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`

Comment: this is pivot problem you can try search how to pivot  with for loop like pd.concat([df.pivot() for x in ['store', 'quantity'])])

Comment: @anky_91 that is fine my friend, you can keep your answer here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt` and `pivot_table()`:

```
m=df.melt(['store','quantity'])
```

---

```
m.pivot_table(index='value',columns='store',values='quantity',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
```

---

```
store   A  B
value       
black   0  5
medium  0  4
red     2  0
small   2  1
```

Comment: I'm traveling, so may can not reply it in time with small screen of my phone(iphone4 ....)

Comment: @anky_91 Wow - pandas wizardry. Thanks a lot!